# Laravel: Acceder a valor de una tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Tengo en la base de datos una tabla de personas que tienen asignado el id de la ciudad en la que están, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el modelo *Persona* establezco la relación entre la persona y su ciudad:

```
class Persona extends Model
{
    public function ciudad() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class, 'ciudad');
    }
}
```

En el controlador hago una consulta de todas la personas *con la relación de ciudades*:

```
class PersonaController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $personas = Persona::with('ciudad')->orderBy('id')->get();
    }
}
```

Cuando hago un `dd($personas)` en el controlador, compruebo que la relación queda correctamente establecida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí podemos ver que el usuario pertenece a la ciudad de Puerto Vallarta (devuelta por el id `918` presente en tabla Personas). Pues bien, en la vista itero sobre todas las personas obteniendo sus datos, incluyendo la ciudad:

```
@foreach($personas as $persona)
<tr>
    [...]
    <td>{{ $almacen->ciudad }}</td>
    [...]
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Así se ve...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando `$persona->ciudad` devuelve solo el ID.

Si uso `$persona->ciudad()->nombre` devuelve error ("*Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$nombre*").

Si uso `$persona->ciudad->nombre` devuelve error ("*Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object*").

¿Cómo obtengo los *nombres* de la ciudades?

Comment: Colocarías por favor la consulta que estas haciendo, así como la forma en que estas iterando los valores en tu vista?

Comment: Listo, ya añadí esa información!

Comment: En la tabla que muestras, la columna `ciudad` es la llave foránea que te vincula con la tabla ciudad cierto?

Comment: Sí Aprendiz, así es. Pero en el modelo ```Ciudad``` no tengo definida la relación.

Comment: El nombre del campo es el mismo que el de la relación. Prueba cambiar el nombre a uno de los dos

Comment: Ese problema lo resolví justamente así con una relación anterior. Quiero ver qué otro modo tengo para resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debes usar un nombre para una relación que ya sea el nombre de una columna, de lo contrario recibirás siempre el valor de la columna, cambia uno de ellos, lo más fácil aquí es el nombre de la relación:

```php
public function ciudadRelacionada() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class, 'ciudad');
}
```

Entonces obtendrás la ciudad relacionada así:

```php
$persona->ciudadRelacionada
```

O uno de sus atributos:

```php
$persona->ciudadRelacionada->nombre
```

NOTA: Pero si deseas seguir las convenciones, deberías reemplazar el nombre de la columna por `ciudad_id`, de modo que la relación te quedaría:

```php
public function ciudad() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class); // eloquent interpretará que la fk es el nombre de la clase en snakecase seguido de _id, o sea 'ciudad_id' 
}
```

Y obtendrás la ciudad relacionada así:

```php
$persona->ciudad
```

O uno de sus atributos:

```php
$persona->ciudad->nombre
```

---

BONUS: Como cambiar el nombre de la columna.

Crea una migración:

```php
php artisan make:migration renombrar_columna_ciudad
```

Y en la migración:

```php
class RenombrarColumnaCiudad extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('personas', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('ciudad', 'ciudad_id');
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('personas', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('ciudad_id', 'ciudad');
        });
    }

}
```

Ejecuta la migración:

```php
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Excelente maestro! Gracias.